# почему сайт выдает ошибку, если по выводу у меня все правильно?

Tags: python-3.x

при запуске данного кода, на сайте не пропускает по решению
[image: вот такую ошибку выдает]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вроде бы у Вас тест пишет конкретную ошибку- неправильно обрбатывается "None". Как я понимаю, Ваше решение не пропускает система из за того, что решение должно нормально обрабатывать не только "правильный", но и "неправильный" ввод

Comment: @S.H. Нет, тест пишет, что None не равно 'Even' или None не равно 'Odd'. Потому что оно ожидается, что функция должна вернуть одно из этих значений, а у автора вопроса функция ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в этом задании вам нужно написать функцию, которая **возвращает** результат. А ваша функция ничего не возвращает, а только выводит на печать.

Замените оба `print` на `return` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: спасибо, сам долго понять не мог, что же не так)